# Предупреждения о непоследовательных изменениях переменной

Tags: c++, c++17

```
int main() {
    int x{};
    x = x++;
}
```

Почему эта программа выдаёт следующие предупреждения в gcc и clang ([1](https://godbolt.org/z/POzP1A) и [2](https://godbolt.org/z/KqejGR))?

> *gcc* - **warning:** operation on `x` may be undefined
>
> *clang* - **warning:** multiple unsequenced modifications to `x`

Comment: интересуюсь - что значат фигурные скобки после `x`?

Comment: @Igor uniform initialization, для int будет 0

Comment: Точно? `int i{};     // uninitialized built-in type`

Comment: @MBo ну вот в первом примере такое же http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3.9. Какой у вас компилятор?

Comment: Я просто цитату нашёл относительно uniform initialization в C++11. Но в авторитетном источнике пока не вижу.

Comment: @MBo цитату из черновика стандарта? Можете привести пункт?

Comment: @MBo cppquestions все правильно говорит. Если скобки пустые, то uniform initialization приводит к [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), которая, в свою очередь, не-классы инициализирует нулями: [*"otherwise (если это не объект класса), the object is zero-initialized"*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да, по этой ссылке в примере есть  `int n{};                // scalar => zero-initialization, the value is 0`

Comment: Неопределено сначала что выполнять:  x++  потом   x = x   или наоборот?...  Что вы в итоге хотите получать:  ++x    или  x++ , даже  я сейчас не понимаю, а вы хотите чтобы программа разобралась что вам нужно...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Потому что ни GCC, ни Clang на сегодняшний день еще не реализовали поддержку современных свойств ядра языка (core language) С++17 и/или не привели в соответствие с ними свою систему диагностических сообщений. Этот код имеет вполне определенное поведение в C++17, но не в C++14.

В С++14 и ранее побочный эффект оператора присваивания (занесение в `x` значения `0`) и побочный эффект оператора `++` (занесение в `x` значения `1`) никак не упорядочены между собой. Формально поведение не определено, а практически эти эффекты могут произойти в любом порядке, т.е. финальное значение `x` может оказаться как `0` так и `1`.

С++17 ввел требование полного упорядочения в операторе присваивания: правый операнд (вместе со всеми своими побочным эффектами) упорядочен *перед* левым, а побочный эффект всего присваивания упорядочен *после* вычисления обоих операндов. Т.е. `x` должен однозначно получать значение `0`. Это требование еще не реализовано в вышеупомянутых компиляторах.

В данном случае оба компилятора "попадают" в правильное значение, несмотря на предупреждения. Но в более хитрых примерах поведение может быть неправильным. Например, вот такая наивная попытка "обмена байтов"

```
unsigned x = 0xaabb;
((x ^= (x >> 8)) ^= ((x & 0xFF) << 8)) ^= (x >> 8);
std::cout << std::hex << x << std::endl;
```

не должна обменивать байты. Правильный результат - `0x11bb` в `x`. Clang "попадает" и в него, а вот в GCC `x` получает значение `0xbbaa`, что неправильно.

Comment: А можно немного подробнее? В данном конкретном примере к чему это приходит?

Comment: Соответствующие репорты в [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83028) и [clang](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35340)

Comment: Я бы ещё добавил, что ни в gcc, ни в clang это не хотят исправлять.

Comment: куда подробнее? Все подробно рассказано

Comment: @ixSci в `clang` исправили, ждём `gcc` :)

Comment: @cppquestions ага, мне приходят уведомления, я же их создал :)